# Prevent default a link which was added dynamically in jquery 3.6

Tags: html, jquery

I wanna preventDefault a dynamically added link that is not getting recognized by the on() method. However, the static link which was already on the page preventDefault()'s itself with the same function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Testing Phase
    </title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txt").focus();
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                var inpt = $("#txt").val();
                $("#dv").append("<p class='eo'>"+inpt+"--><a href='dynamic' class=''>This is dynamic link, it won't get preventDefault() with the on() method.</a></p>");
                x++;
            });
            $('.eo').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt" name="">
<input type="button" id="btn" name="" value="Add">
<div id="dv">
    <a href="nowhere" class="eo">This static link works with the on() method!</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `x++;`? How do you know the link event isn't bubbling?

Comment: ohh, that was used for generating id